# Random black box on desktop

Tags: windows-10-desktop

[Image of Random black box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw7Cu.jpg)

Started up my computer and have this random black box on my desktop.I can only move it around and have no way of closing it. Anyone know how what the cause it and how to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update display driver
Windows Key+X (Or right click on Start)
Click Device Manager
Expand Display Adapter
Right click on entry below
Click Update Driver Software
Click Browse my computer for driver software
Click Let my pick from a list of device drivers on my computer
Choose the driver
Click Next to update
If this does not work, select Search automatically for the updated driver in place of Browse my computer for driver software
Restart your computer

OR

Update driver from manufacturer's website
Go to the website of the display adapter's manufacturer or computer's manufacturer
See if some driver is released for your model and OS
If yes, download that
In Option 2, you click Update Driver Software, in place of this, click Uninstall
Install the downloaded driver
Restart your computer

Comment: My graphic drivers and windows is up to date. When my pc shutdown it also states that GSPY is preventing shutdown. In device manager there is nothing about GSPY as well. Could this be a issue caused by MSI dragon center as I saw reddit feeds related to it?

Comment: @RennY have you connected any gps enabled device to your pc?

Comment: No, nothing and under device manager there is no GSPY device listed

Comment: Try entering this command in cmd DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth